# How do you prevent SharePoint from resetting primary key numbers

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-access

I have an MS Access 2016 database storing its back end on a SharePoint online site for one or our teams.

Another team within our agency wants to use the same database for their site.  I must upload the same database skeleton and lookup tables and their information to the new site.

The development team leader (cannot be contradicted) insists that both sites' have the same primary keys for all lookup items.

Whenever I upload a table from a backend in Access, SharePoint resets the primary keys starting with the number one and continuing sequentially until finished. If any changes were made since the tables were uploaded, when those tables are localized and then uploaded to a new site, SharePoint changes the primary keys to remove the gaps in numbers that exist because of deleted entries or changes.

Is there a way to bypass this issue?  Do I need to create a redundant primary key field that will not be changed when the table is uploaded to the new site?  Creating a redundant key means that all the tables on the old site will need to be updated to include this field, and the entire front end (queries and forms) will need to be revised for both sites to use the same interface.

Please tell me there is an easier way to ensure the primary keys are the same.

Thanks
Tammy